# How store hexadecimal strings in a Byte array?

Tags: java, arrays

I need help to create the header as explain below, I am not confident with byte conversion and big endian convention.

I think my problem comes from the lines `byte[] VERSION = "01".getBytes();` I don't know how to 'force' the String to be stored in one byte.

**Header creation**

```
public static final int HEADER_SIZE = 8;
byte[] header = new byte[HEADER_SIZE];

// Header struture
/*
*byte 0   : Version
*byte 1   : Inverse Version
*byte 2-3 : Type
*byte 4-7 : Length
*/

// Hex values
byte[] VERSION = "01".getBytes();
byte[] INVERSE_VERSION = "FE".getBytes();
byte[] TYPE = "9000".getBytes();
byte[] LENGTH = "02".getBytes();

ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(this.header);
    buf.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
    buf.put(VERSION);
    buf.put(INVERS_VERSION);
    buf.put(TYPE);
    //buf.put(LENGTH); <-- Overflow

//out
System.out.println(new String(buf.array(), "ASCII"));
```

**Actual Output**

```
01FE9000
```

**Output Expected**

```
01FE900020000000
```

Comment: did you missed this code `byte[] LENGTH = "02".getBytes();`

Comment: how do you expect this `01FE900000000002` and not this `01FE900002000000`?

Comment: Hexadecimal is a representation, not a data type.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args){

        long hex1 = 0x01;
        long hex2 = 0xFF;
        long hex3 = 0x9000;
        long hex4 = 0x20000000;

        long hexResult = hex4 | (hex3<<32) | (hex2<<(32+16)) | (hex1<<(32+16+8));

        String S_result_unpadded = Long.toHexString(hexResult);
        System.out.println("Hex string unpadded : " + S_result_unpadded);

        String S_result_padded = String.format("%16s", S_result_unpadded).replace(' ', '0');
        System.out.println("Hex string unpadded : " + S_result_padded);
    }`

Comment: Since I can't post an answer I posted here what helped me after few experiments...